# Gmail contextual gadget does not show up

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

Steps to reproduce:

1. Log into Gmail.
2. Click on the cog icon in the top-left corner; then click on Settings.
3. Click on the Labs tab.
4. Enable "Add any gadget by URL" feature.
5. After reload, go back to the Settings page.
6. Click on the Gadgets tab.
7. Add this URL: https://googledrive.com/host/0B0JNj_IM2wiPb1NaX1B0S29MQlE/helloworldgadget.xml
8. Go to an email that has the string "Hello World" in its subject or body. Notice that the gadget does not show up.